# Redux thunks affecting different reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In my application I have some a thunk that runs that dispatches a thunk

```js
...
   return async(dispatch) => {
   const data = await fetch(someurl)
   const json = data.json()
   dispatch({
    type:'LOAD_IDS',
    payload:json
   })
  }
```

Which loads in data into the store in one reducer

```js
 case 'LOAD_IDS': {
            return {
                ...state,
                graph_palette_ids: action.payload
            }
        }
```

After that , I dispatch some more actions

```js
  return async(dispatch) => {
        const test_type = await getJSON(someurl)

        dispatch({
            type: 'LOAD_WIZARD_TAGS',
            payload: {
                test_type,

            }
        })
    }
```

Which change the state in a **seperate reducer to the first one**

```js
case 'LOAD_WIZARD_TAGS':
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    test_type_tags: action.payload.test_type,

                }
            }
```

However , redux dev tools tells me that the second action is overriding the data from the first action, even though they are in seperate reducers.

The data is reset to the inital state of the reducer

Comment: please include your default case from both reducers